# SharePoint user access

Tags: permissions, sharepoint

I want to find all places (lists, sites, etc.) in SP where a specific user has access, in order to remove permissions for a terminated employee.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In case employee is terminated i.e. disabled in Active Directory (s)he will not be able to login and access the site anymore. Unfortunately there is no easy way to find where this user was given access across your SharePoint farm, the only way (AFAIK) is to use a third party tool or to develop your own custom report.